# Swift KVC setting a NSNumber value to String key

Tags: swift, kvc

I have an object with a String property. I have to use key-value-coding to set that property from outside. Therefore, I am using `self.setValue(value, forKeyPath: key)`.

Problem here is that I can set a NSNumber as value which results in a crash with message `-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. How can I do a type check between the value and the property to avoid the crash?

value gives me NSObject back as dynamicType. 
And `obj.valueForKey(key).dynamicType` gives me back AnyObject?

What I tried, and could do is something like:

```
if (obj.valueForKey(key) is String && value is String) {...}
```

The thing is that my object has obviously more than one String property, it has many properties. And what I try to do is run through all properties and set them to a specific value from a web service. Now, I need a generic data type check to see if there are type mismatches, something like

```
if (obj.valueForKey(key).realtype == value.realtype) {...}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `setValue:forKeyPath:` rather than just setting the value directly?

Comment: It would be good to be able to see your class...

Comment: because this is part of a parser that retrieves data from a objc library and sets the values in several swift objects. I only have the parent class of the objects not the actual class. I dont want to cast it to the actual class because there are many and I would need a huge if/switch statement to go through them all.

Comment: This is the sort of thing you use a protocol for. Make your objects conform to a protocol that declares the properties that you want to set. That way you don't need the actual type of each object, just it's protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that your keyPath accepts a String, the you could use Swift `as?` operator to ensure the value you are assigning can be cast to it.
Something like:

```
self.setValue(value as? String ?? "Bad value", forKeyPath: key)
```

By doing this, you ensure that you pass the right value for the property (after casting), or a default value in case the case does not succeed.